# always preserve URL when redirecting to subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I want to redirect all requests to a certain path on my server (/app) to a subdirectory at /app/app_site. Following rewrite rules do the job for requests like 'http://localhost/app/somepage.htm':

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/app_site.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app_site.*$
RewriteRule ^/app(.*)     /app/app_site$1 [L,PT]
```

This results in the correct page, while preserving the URL. Also, 'http://localhost/app/' will fetch the index page at /app/app_site/index.html, while preserving the URL 'http://localhost/app/'.

However, when I enter 'http://localhost/app', following things happen:

- the correct page is fetched, at /app/app_site/index.html
- yet, the URL is redirected to 'http://localhost/app/app_site/'

I'm nearly there, but would like to preserve the URL in all cases (also those without trailing slash). Anyone have a clue how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour with [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) enabled, because you've rewritten to a directory that lacks a trailing slash, and `mod_dir` performs this cleanup after you've rewritten the URL with `mod_rewrite`.

The easiest solution is to rewrite the URL so that it always at least matches the slash-terminated directory path, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/app_site.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app_site.*$
RewriteRule ^/app/?(.*)$     /app/app_site/$1 [L,PT]
```

This prevents `mod_dir` from having to add the trailing slash, and therefore avoids the external redirection to `/app/app_site/` you're experiencing now.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a million! This works like a charm for this example. However, there's still a problem with my real app. I simplified the example, but actually, /app is a Cocoon app served via Tomcat through mod_jk. Now, whenever I activate the mod_jk directive, "http://localhost/app" and "http://localhost/app/" are rewritten to "http://localhost/app/app_site/" (all URLs with further paths are preserved, though). Do you happen to know what causes this interference and how to solve it?

Comment: They're rewritten in the sense that the URL is changed in the user's browser? How do you have your `mod_jk` handler defined?

Comment: Hi Tim, I've investigated this furher and was put on the right track by your answer. I have no special options configured for the mod_jk handler; just one rule: /app|/*=ajp13.
I realised that my cocoon app's sitemap.xmap specifies a redirection, too, for serving a default homepage when the empty path ('/app/') is requested: 
  <map:match pattern="">
    <map:redirect-to uri="appindex.xml"/>
  </map:match>
This passes on the request to another cocoon pipeline. As it happens, this is equivalent to an external redirect, causing the URL ('/app/') to be rewritten as '/app/appindex.xml'. [...]

Comment: [...] Of course, when served via mod_jk, this redirection happens on the URL that had been rewritten by mod_rewrite, causing "http://localhost/app/" to be rewritten as "http://localhost/app/app_site/appindex.xml". I could solve this by specifying the cocoon redirect as an internal redirect, by prefixing the "cocoon:/" schema:
  <map:match pattern="">
    <map:redirect-to uri="cocoon:/appindex.xml"/>
  </map:match>
This works: it preserves the URL "http://localhost/app/", while serving /app/app_site/appindex.xml.
So, thanks again! As soon as I have sufficient credits, I'll vote your answer up.